# How could I move the button to the right side of the navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQdfF.png)The "Client Area" button needs to move to the right side of the navigation bar, but when I tried a few things I couldn't get it to move from the place it is in as of right now.
I tried some things but it would not work. What is a good way to resolve this issue. I couldn't a sollution to get this working.

```css
/* Main website */

* {
  background-color: #232323;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}


/* Navigation bar */


/* Navigation items */

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000f14;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #000f14;
}

.navbar img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.navbar a {
  background: #000f14;
}


/* Navigation  Client area Button */

.btn {
  border: 2.5px solid #053F74;
  background-color: #000f14;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #053F74;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar__container">
    <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/index.html"><img src="/images/AquaTech navbar logo.png" alt="navbar__logo"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="clients.html">Clients</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
      <a href="login.html"><button class="btn">Client Area</button></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image: Picture of a navigation menu]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xukmb.png)

Comment: Client Area shows up on the right for me...

Comment: @canon If you fullscreen it you'll see the client area doesn't extend to the right side of the screen

Comment: Note that your HTML is invalid. A `<a>` can't be a child of a `<ul>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `margin-inline: auto 0` to your anchor element. Some info on how to use margins from Kevin Powell [here](https://youtu.be/Azfj1efPAH0) and [here](https://youtu.be/pSJcpOSNjMI).

```css
/* Main website */

* {
  background-color: #232323;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}


/* Navigation bar */


/* Navigation items */

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000f14;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #000f14;
}

.navbar img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.navbar a {
  background: #000f14;
}


/* Navigation  Client area Button */

.btn {
  border: 2.5px solid #053F74;
  background-color: #000f14;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #053F74;
}

/* added this class */
.align-right {
  margin-inline: auto 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar__container">
    <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/index.html"><img src="/images/AquaTech navbar logo.png" alt="navbar__logo"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="clients.html">Clients</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
      <a class='align-right' href="login.html"><button class="btn">Client Area</button></a><!-- added the class 'align-right' to the <a> element -->
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The other way I do this sometimes is to add a dummy element as a spacer and use flex-grow to push the elements beside it to the left and right.

```css
/* Main website */

* {
  background-color: #232323;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}


/* Navigation bar */


/* Navigation items */

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000f14;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #000f14;
}

.navbar img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.navbar a {
  background: #000f14;
}


/* Navigation  Client area Button */

.btn {
  border: 2.5px solid #053F74;
  background-color: #000f14;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #053F74;
}

/* added this class */
.spacer {
  flex-grow:2;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar__container">
    <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/index.html"><img src="/images/AquaTech navbar logo.png" alt="navbar__logo"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="clients.html">Clients</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
      <li class='spacer'></li><!-- added this spacer element  -->
      <a href="login.html"><button class="btn">Client Area</button></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an element right before "Client area" and use `margin:auto` or use `flex-grow: 1`.

```css
/* Main website */

* {
  background-color: #232323;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}


/* Navigation bar */


/* Navigation items */

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000f14;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.navbar ul .spacer {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.navbar li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #000f14;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar__container">
    <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/index.html"><img src="/images/AquaTech navbar logo.png" alt="navbar__logo"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="clients.html">Clients</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <a href="login.html"><button class="btn">Client Area</button></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```